# Criteria addOrder to order by trim(field)?

Tags: hibernate, criteria

All is in this question, here is my method.

```
public List<Object> listEntry(final int rowNumMin, final int maxResult,
    final String orderField, final int orderSort) {

    final Criteria requete = getSession().createCriteria(
            getPersistentClass());
    if(orderSort=1){
        requete.addOrder(Order.asc(orderField));
    } else {
        requete.addOrder(Order.desc(orderField));
    }
    requete.setMaxResults(maxResult);
    requete.setFirstResult(rowNumMin);
    final List<Object> resultat = requete.list();
    return resultat;
}
```

This is like

```
SELECT * FROM myTable ORDER BY orderField LIMIT rowNumMin, maxResult;
```

but I would like to obtain

```
SELECT * FROM myTable ORDER BY TRIM(orderField) LIMIT rowNumMin, maxResult;
```

How can I do this ?

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to create a custom subclass of `org.hibernate.criterion.Order`, and override the `toSqlString` method to generate the SQL `order by` clause you want.

And then use `criteria.addOrder(new TrimOrder("orderField", true))`.