# Hibernate return empty result if using LIKE condition with univarchar columns (Sybase)

Tags: sql, hibernate, unicode

Let's suppose I have a table: Person(Name: univarchar) and this table contains a row "abc".
I search Person by using Hibernate (Criteria API and HQL):

Criteria API:

```
Criteria c = session.createCriteria(Person.class);
c.add(Restrictions.ilike(name,"abc"));
return c.list();
```

HQL:

```
String query = "from Person where lower(name) like :name";
Query q = session.createQuery(query);
query.setString("name","abc");
return query.list();
```

It return empty result. However, when I use Interactive SQL of Sybase to execute SQL statement that is generated by Hibernate, it return a row "abc".

I found a solution for HQL case. This is to use rtrim function:

```
String query = "from Person where lower(rtrim(name)) like :name";
...
```

But my problem is I want to use Criteria API and I cannot find any ways to trim name column by using Criteria API.

Thanks and sorry for my poor English.

Comment: have you tried with `Restrictions.like(...)`. Why you are using `ilike`? you want to do case-sensitive search..

Comment: Yes, that is reason why i use ilike. But I have tried Restrictions.like(...) and it has the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried with this code :

```
Criteria c = session.createCriteria(Person.class);
c.add(Restrictions.ilike(name,"abc",MatchMode.ANYWHERE));
return c.list();
```

If this will not work then [Read this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8987969/criteria-addorder-to-order-by-trimfield). Its similar Just he wants to trim while `Order` you want to trim while `Restrictions`.